# Sorting folders with bash

Tags: shell, unix

My root folder structure is like this:

```
My Family - Holiday
My Birthday[15.11]
Name-Name[1]
Name1
Name2
...
```

Now, I want every folder which contains a `.info` file to move to another directory.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

for folder in *
do
    echo $folder
    if [ -e "$folder/*.info" ]
    then
            echo $folder
            mv  $folder ./Finished
    fi
done
```

The echoes are only for testing.
I have found that every time a non-escaped character is in the name that the `if` is failing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Put `$folder` in quotes.  I.e. `mv "$Folder" ./Finished/`.  See below.

Comment: Quote you `$folder` in `mv`. The command would be `mv "$folder" ./Finished`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is that you cannot use `test -e *.info`.  You can parse the output of ls to check for the file.  There are issues with parsing ls, but they are much less significant than many people make them out to be.  If you do not allow newlines in filenames, the following should work:

```
#!/bin/sh

for dir in *; do
    if ls -f "$dir" | grep -q '\.info$'; then
        mv "$dir" ./Finished
    fi
done
```

Do note that it is essential that no filenames have an embedded newline, since this will incorrectly identify a file named `foo.info\nbar` as if there were a single file named `foo.info`.  In reality, this is unlikely to be a significant issue.  If this is an issue, you will not want to use the shell for this, although you could do:

```
#!/bin/sh

for dir in *; do
    for f in "$dir"/*; do
        case "$f" in 
            *.info) mv "$dir" ./Finished; break;;
        esac
    done
done
```

Answer (score 6):

Bash wants you to quote your variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" = "-v" ]]; then
    Verbose=true
    vopt="-v"
    shift
else
    Verbose=false
    vopt=""
fi

for folder in *; do
    $Verbose && printf "%s" "$folder"
    if [[ -e "$folder/*.info" ]]; then
            if mv "$vopt" "$folder" ./Finished/; then
                $Verbose && echo -n " ... done"
            fi
    fi
    $Verbose && echo ""
done
```

Note that it's a good idea to end your target directory with a slash.  That way, if for some reason the `Finished` directory disappears, you'll get an error rather than silently renaming the first $folder to Finished, then moving all the other matches into the first match.

Note also that I'm using `printf` for some of the debugging output just in case one of your `$folder`s starts with a hyphen.

**UPDATE #1**: you now have debugging controlled with the `-v` option.

**UPDATE #2**: I just realized that you are checking for the existence of `*.info`, literally.  Note:

```
ghoti@pc ~$ mkdir foo
ghoti@pc ~$ touch foo/\*.info
ghoti@pc ~$ ls -la foo
total 0
-rw-r--r--   1 ghoti  ghoti    0  8 Aug 07:45 *.info
drwxr-xr-x   3 ghoti  ghoti  102  8 Aug 07:45 .
drwx------+ 10 ghoti  ghoti  340  8 Aug 07:44 ..
ghoti@pc ~$ [[ -e "foo/*.info" ]] && echo yes
yes
ghoti@pc ~$ mv foo/\*.info foo/bar.info
ghoti@pc ~$ [[ -e "foo/*.info" ]] && echo yes
ghoti@pc ~$
```

If what you really want to find is "any file ending in .info", then `[[ -e` is not the way to go.  Pls confirm before I work more on this answer.  :)

**UPDATE #3**:

Here's a version that finds moves your folder if the folder conains any .info file.  Note that this does *not* grep the output of `ls`.

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$ cat doit 
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" = "-v" ]]; then
    Verbose=true
    vopt="-v"
    shift
else
    Verbose=false
    vopt=""
fi

for folder in *; do

    infofile="$(
        if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
            cd "$folder"
            for file in *.info; do
              if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
                  echo "$file"
                  break
              fi
            done
        fi
    )"

    if [[ -f "$folder/$infofile" ]]; then
        mv "$vopt" "$folder" ./Finished/
    elif $Verbose; then
        printf "%s ... skipped\n" "$folder"
    fi

done
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$ find . -print
.
./doit
./baz
./foo
./foo/bar.info
./Finished
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$ ./doit -v
Finished ... skipped
baz ... skipped
doit ... skipped
foo -> ./Finished/foo
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp1]$
```

Comment: hm.. it doesn'T work for me, i only get a lot of empty line when i remove the printf :/ printf is good for the debugging, but it never enters the if-statement

Comment: Does it move things?  Another option for debugging is to add a `-v` option to move, so it tells you when it's running.  I've added more debugging control to the answer.  I would expect that if `echo " ... done"` is not executed, it is because the `mv` has failed and returned an error, but you might want to include an `else` for that `if` to debug that condition more completely.

Comment: Yes, i'm looking for a *.info the reason is, that the .info file has a random name,so i have used the wildcard.
Each folder contains only 1 .info file.
When there were only character like [a-zA-z] in the nameof folders my script worked without problems.

Comment: Ah, a wildcard is quite different from a literal asterisk, as you can see from my second update above.  I'll see what I can do to adjust this.

Comment: @demonking - what should happen if there are multiple .info files?  Assume there's an error, and don't move the directory?

Comment: @demonking - please see Update #3.  While it's quite a bit longer, it should correctly find arbitrarily-named `.info` files per your requirements.

Comment: mv: cannot stat `': No such file or directory


#was the output

Comment: Ah - you know, I never tested this without using the `-v` option.  I suspect it will work if you include that.  Or if you remove the quotes around `$vopt` on the `mv` line.  Since `"$vopt"` evaluates to an empty string if the variable is empty, `mv` is trying to move an empty file into the target, which of course won't work.  Since $vopt is controlled within the script, you aren't at risk by removing quotes in this case.  (This could be handled more cleanly, but I think I've spent enough time on this answer.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    PATH_TO_FOLDER="/YOUR_FOLDER"

    for f in `ls $PATH_TO_FOLDER`;
    do
        # Check filename

        if [ $(echo $f | grep -Ec ".info$") -ne 1 ]
        then
            echo "We don't care"
        else
            ## move the file
        fi
    done
```

Comment: Don't do this.  Perfect example to the [Parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem.

Comment: There's nothing personal about downvotes. They're just used to indicate when an answer is flawed or otherwise problematic. In this case, you iterate over files in an unsafe way. Did you read the post @ghoti gave?

Comment: Apart from the parsing problem, it is also an example of resource waste. Two forks per file in the echo/grep pipe just to test if a string contains ".info". This is done in the shell without forking with `case $f in; (*.info) move it; esac`.

Comment: @TOC - I provided one of the downvotes, I don't know who provided the other.  I can assure you, it's nothing personal.  I don't know you.  All I see is an answer that (1) won't work with certain filenames, (2) doesn't match the OP's directory structure, (3) wastes resources as Jens said and (4) doesn't even move the file.  A bad answer, worthy of a downvote.

Comment: +1  Although there are problems with this solution, there is no way to check for the existence of a file with a random string ending in a fixed string other than using some form of readdir to look at filenames, and parsing ls is the only way to do that in the shell.  If whitespace and other special characters are a concern, the problem cannot be solved accurately in sh.  But `ls | grep '.info$'` is probably good enough.

Comment: @WilliamPursell : You're wright about ending and error checking. Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - I believe you are incorrect on this one.  Please see "Update #3" in my answer.  I would value your feedback.

Comment: @ghoti  Indeed, it can be done without parsing ls, but I think using `case` is a bit cleaner than the solution you provide.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - ah, very nice answer you provided.  I guess we both disproved that "parsing ls is the only way to do that in the shell".